# svmono: Space below heading

Tags: spacing

How can I reduce the space below the chapter name when using the document class svomono in this version
[file](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bqzgybtg6oejonj/AAAyRnGvNSg-v_wZezUO_0V_a?dl=0)
In the MWE the space between "My chapter" and "Text" is too big.
Best would be a solution without manipulating svmono1.cls.

```
\documentclass[envcountchap]{svmono}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My Chapter}

Text ...
\end{document}
```

With `\usepackage{titlesec}` and `\titlespacing` (see below) the problem is that it writes "chapter 1" what I do not want.
When I do not use [display], it' completely gone. At the beginning of a chapter just the chapter number should be there and a horizontal line below (as in svmono normally).

```
\documentclass{svmono}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

% altering spacing after chapter name (third length argument) to 0
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}

Text

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `svmono` class is for submissions to Springer. Do as *they* want.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines after the `\documentclass` command.

```
\documentclass[envcountchap]{svmono}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@makechapterhead{\@tempdima=167}{\@tempdima=50}{}{}% Modify 50 to change the space
\makeatother
```

Comment: In principle your idea should work. But with this version of svmono (I edited my post and put a link) it does not work. Do you know why?

Comment: My solution modifies `svmono.cls` as little or as much as any attempt to tweak the chapter heading with `titlesec`. Apparently `svmono` is not compatible with `titlesec` (otherwise your attempt would work), so you can either use a standard class (`svmono` is not standard, but idiosyncratic to Springer), or be happy with what `svmono.cls` does (after all, why do you use this class if you don't like its look?), or patch it as I suggested.

Comment: titlesec is compatible with svmono (see second code in updated post, but this has other disadvantages as I added there. Thats why I liked your suggestion). With you question about another class you're right, but I am working with thwo other authors on a book and we are in the final step...